# jquery tiny scroll bar custom css image

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar

i work with [tiny scroll bar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/)  plugin. in orginal, we have any thumb image for scrollbar with `width=13px;` and `height=480px`. i change orginal image to `width=10px` and `height=480px`. now i see top of scrollbar not complete and Is cut. whats problem. how to fix this?! [NOT WORK DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BBKING/Njgq8/)

with custom image 10*480 :
[image]

with orginal image 13*480 :
[image]

**EDIT:**
User [Sowmya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12248205/1313483) have a any idea for fix this problem using CSS3 and border radius method.

yes,right. this worked with this css in major browsers ***except IE6-8***:

```
border-radius: 20px; /* Standard */
-o-border-radius: 20px; /* Opera 10.x */
-moz-border-radius: 20px; /* Mozilla/Firefox */
-icab-border-radius: 20px; /* iCab */
-khtml-border-radius: 20px; /* KHTML/Konqueror */
-webkit-border-radius: 20px; /* Webkit/Safari/Chrome/etc… */
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using image you can use background color with border radius. Check the updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Njgq8/2/) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Njgq8/2/)

Comment: CSS border radius not work in IE 6 - 8 and we need to any fixer ie: [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/)(uses .htc files and the behavior property to implement CSS3 into IE 6 - 8) Or [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) (is a bit of javascript that will put classes on your html element). I think better way is fix this problem with other way.

Comment: In case anyone struggles as much as I did getting this to work - the trick is increasing the 'height' of #scroll .thumb .end from the default 5 to 20, so that the border-radius has enough room to work.